# Cannot get innerHTML from WebElement which is confirmed to be present

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to get the innerHTML value from this HTML, using Selenium WebDriver.

```html
<div class="map-overlay-network">Newham : NSG Designated Streets (Type 1/2)</div>
```

This piece of code should confirm that the element is present:

```
public boolean isMapOverlayNetworkPresent() {

    By byExpression = By.className(mapOverlayNetworkClassName);
    return isWebElementPresent(byExpression);

}
```

My elements are defined at the top of the class:

```
private static final String mapOverlayNetworkClassName = "map-overlay-network";
@FindBy(className=mapOverlayNetworkClassName) private WebElement mapOverlayNetwork;
```

This is the code for function isMapOverlayNetworkPresent:

```
public boolean isWebElementPresent(By byExpression) {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    try { 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byExpression));
        return true;

    } catch (TimeoutException e) {

        System.out.println("Timeout waiting for presence of element " + byExpression);
        return false;

    }

}
```

Here is where I try to get the innerHTML:

```
public String returnDefaultNetwork() {

    String defaultNetwork = mapOverlayNetwork.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    System.out.println("Default network = " + defaultNetwork);
    return defaultNetwork;

}
```

This is the report from my console:

```
Is default network shown on map: true
Default network =
```

If I load the page in Firefox and use Developer Tools, I can see the element using the inspector. If I right click on the element in the Inspector & select Copy InnerHTML, I get this value:

Newham : NSG Designated Streets (Type 1/2)

This is the value I want.

This does not work in any of the browsers I am testing, i.e. Firefox, Chrome or Edge.

Any suggestions?

A previous element on the screen works fine. This is how it looks in HTML:

```html
<div class="map-overlay-customer">Newham</div>
```

This is how it is defined in my PageObject class:

```
public static final String mapOverlayCustomerClassName = "map-overlay-customer";
@FindBy(className=mapOverlayCustomerClassName) private WebElement mapOverlayCustomer;
```

This is me returning the InnerHTML:

```
public String returnDefaultCustomer() {

    return mapOverlayCustomer.getAttribute("innerHTML");

}
```

This is the response from the console:

```
Default customer: Newham
```

Update 21/12/2017

Following a suggestion below, I added a wait for visibility after detecting the presence of my element.

```
private void waitForVisibility(WebElement element) throws Error {

    // time out in seconds
    try {

         new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));

    } catch (TimeoutException e) {

         System.out.println("Timeout waiting for presence of element " + element);

    }

}

public boolean isMapOverlayNetworkVisible() {

    waitForVisibility(mapOverlayNetwork);
    return mapOverlayNetwork.isDisplayed();

}
```

In my Test class:

```
reportAssert("Is default network present on map", alloyLoggedInPage.isMapOverlayNetworkPresent());

reportAssert("Is default network visible on map", alloyLoggedInPage.isMapOverlayNetworkVisible());

System.out.println("Default network: " + alloyLoggedInPage.returnDefaultNetwork());
```

My result:

```
Is default network present on map: true
Is default network visible on map: true
Get default network.
Default network = Newham : NSG Designated Streets (Type 1/2)
Default network: Newham : NSG Designated Streets (Type 1/2)
```

Comment: what happens if you try getAttribute("textContent")?

Comment: The `value` of the `class` attribute is enough to indicate that there is an `overlay`. Work for the `overlay`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `.getAttribute("value")` or `.getText()` for your web element.

PS: But it's really strange that `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` does not work.

PSS: Also try to check the value of element in Console of browser by running JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector(".map-overlay-network").innerHTML;
```

PSSS: Also, I want to recommend to add one more wait with `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>‌​)` after your wait, because after your wait element just in DOM, but not visible.

Comment: Thank you @RatmirAsanov. I tried all those options, but still no value. The console command gives a null response. A previous element, which is nigh on identical to this one, does yield a value. Strange!

Comment: @SteveStaple, it means that your locator is wrong (according to the test in Console).

Comment: @SteveStaple, can you add a more extended version of your HTML?

Comment: I don't think so @RatmirAsanov. The previous element works perfectly well in my code, but not with a console command.

Comment: @SteveStaple, sorry, it's my fault. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @SteveStaple, also I want to recommend to add one more wait with `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>)` after your wait. What is happening?

Comment: Thanks @RatmirAsanov. I don't know how, but that worked! Running ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>‌​) first - my expected InnerHTML text is returned!

Comment: @SteveStaple sounds good! I have updated my answer. If my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Comment: @SteveStaple, it means that your element was not visible, but was in DOM (after your wait).